# Getting size of a UIButton and right aligning

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton

I have a UIButton like so:

```
UIButton *inviteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[inviteButton setTitle:@"Invite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[inviteButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:(14.0)]];
[inviteButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

How do I get its height and width so that I canset its frame?

If I do:

```
float width = inviteButton.frame.size.width;
```

then width is always zero.

I want the button to be right aligned in a view I have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually wanted this:

This is deprecated.

```
CGSize size = [[inviteButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] sizeWithFont:inviteButton.titleLabel.font];
```

This is the new way:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:(14.0)]};

CGSize size = [[inviteButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
```

Answer (score 2):

You u have to set height and width for UIButton using frame like this.

```
    inviteButton.frame = CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set width and height with this.

[inviteButton sizeToFit];

after that try to print this

float width = inviteButton.frame.size.width;

and then setframe of button to display on screen at specific postion.

[inviteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, inviteButton.frame.size.width, inviteButton.frame.size.height)]

Answer (score 0):

As I seen you don't set frame of button. So you are getting ZERO return. without set frame you can't get width so first set frame using like this ..

```
inviteButton.frame = CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>);;
```